# Axis2 1.5 With Spring Causing java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 on WebSphere 7

Tags: spring, apache-axis, websphere-7

I am using axis2 (1.5) to host my web services. I am using spring framework for dependency injection to instantiate some classes. I managed to start axis2 after setting up parent-last class loading policy for my axis web module as stated on IBM and Apache websites.

After all this I am getting following exception upon listing the service(s) installed only (I can see axis2 index page, I can list services but as soon as I click any service for its WSDL I get following);

```
10/11/11 22:35:42:483 GMT 00000027 webapp I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Apache-Axis2.
10/11/11 22:35:42:501 GMT 00000027 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/axi
s2
10/11/11 22:35:42:621 GMT 00000027 FfdcProvider I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere7\AppServer\profiles\App
Srv01\logs\ffdc\server1_6d026d02_11.11.10_22.35.42.61837911.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl 272
10/11/11 22:35:43:765 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: addressing-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336N
ode01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.5.5.mar
10/11/11 22:35:43:787 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: jaxws-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336Node01
Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/modules/axis2-jaxws-mar-1.5.5.mar
10/11/11 22:35:43:806 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll10
10336Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.5.5.mar
10/11/11 22:35:43:815 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336N
ode01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.5.5.mar
10/11/11 22:35:43:829 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: ping-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336Node01C
ell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.5.5.mar
10/11/11 22:35:43:837 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: script-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336Node0
1Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/modules/scripting-1.5.5.mar
10/11/11 22:35:43:848 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336
Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.5.5.mar
10/11/11 22:35:43:876 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: addressing-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336N
ode01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/addressing-1.5.5.jar
10/11/11 22:35:43:885 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: jaxws-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336Node01
Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-jaxws-mar-1.5.5.jar
10/11/11 22:35:43:893 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336N
ode01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/mtompolicy-1.5.5.jar
10/11/11 22:35:43:902 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: ping-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336Node01C
ell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/ping-1.5.5.jar
10/11/11 22:35:43:910 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: script-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336Node0
1Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/scripting-1.5.5.jar
10/11/11 22:35:43:919 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.5.5 - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll1010336
Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/soapmonitor-1.5.5.jar
10/11/11 22:35:44:467 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@16cb16cb: display name [org.springfra
mework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@16cb16cb]; startup date Thu Nov 10 22:35:44 GMT 2011; root of context hierarchy
10/11/11 22:35:44:525 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource http://customerServiceContext.xml
10/11/11 22:35:44:723 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying Web service: t24-CustomerService-jws.aar - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedA
pps/hmll1010336Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/services/t24-CustomerService-jws.aar
10/11/11 22:35:44:844 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@463c463c: display name [org.springfra
mework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@463c463c]; startup date Thu Nov 10 22:35:44 GMT 2011; root of context hierarchy
10/11/11 22:35:44:849 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource http://integrationFlowServiceContext.xml
10/11/11 22:35:44:902 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying Web service: t24-IntegrationFlowService-jws.aar - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/ins
talledApps/hmll1010336Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/services/t24-IntegrationFlowService-jws.aar
10/11/11 22:35:44:951 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@65986598: display name [org.springfra
mework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@65986598]; startup date Thu Nov 10 22:35:44 GMT 2011; root of context hierarchy
10/11/11 22:35:44:952 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource http://integrationFrameworkServiceContext.xml
10/11/11 22:35:44:978 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying Web service: t24-IntegrationFrameworkService-jws.aar - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv0
1/installedApps/hmll1010336Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/services/t24-IntegrationFrameworkService-jws.aar
10/11/11 22:35:45:118 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1bc51bc5: display name [org.springfra
mework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1bc51bc5]; startup date Thu Nov 10 22:35:45 GMT 2011; root of context hierarchy
10/11/11 22:35:45:119 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource http://integrationLandscapeServiceContext.xml
10/11/11 22:35:45:288 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying Web service: t24-IntegrationLandscapeService-jws.aar - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv0
1/installedApps/hmll1010336Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/services/t24-IntegrationLandscapeService-jws.aar
10/11/11 22:35:46:131 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ce00ce: display name [org.springframe
work.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ce00ce]; startup date Thu Nov 10 22:35:46 GMT 2011; root of context hierarchy
10/11/11 22:35:46:131 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource http://serviceRepositoryContext.xml
10/11/11 22:35:46:156 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying Web service: t24-ServiceRepository-jws.aar - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installe
dApps/hmll1010336Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/services/t24-ServiceRepository-jws.aar
10/11/11 22:35:46:166 GMT 00000027 SystemOut O INFO Deploying Web service: version-1.5.5.aar - file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/hmll10
10336Node01Cell/axis2_war.ear/axis2.war/WEB-INF/services/version-1.5.5.aar
10/11/11 22:35:46:187 GMT 00000027 servlet I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: axis2_war [/axis2] AxisServlet: Initialization successf
ul.
10/11/11 22:35:46:198 GMT 00000027 webcontainer I com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module Apache-Axis2 has been bound to default_host[
:9080,:80,:9443,:5060,:5061,:443].
10/11/11 22:35:46:211 GMT 00000027 ApplicationMg A WSVR0221I: Application started: axis2_war
10/11/11 22:35:46:215 GMT 00000027 CompositionUn A WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=axis2_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=axis2_war started.
10/11/11 22:35:46:635 GMT 00000024 webcontainer E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /favicon.ico has not been
defined.
10/11/11 22:36:01:130 GMT 00000027 servlet I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: axis2_war [/axis2] [/axis2-web/index.jsp]: Initialization
successful.
10/11/11 22:36:01:163 GMT 00000027 servlet I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: axis2_war [/axis2] [/axis2-web/include/httpbase.jsp]: Ini
tialization successful.
10/11/11 22:36:01:199 GMT 00000027 FfdcProvider I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere7\AppServer\profiles\App
Srv01\logs\ffdc\server1_6d026d02_11.11.10_22.36.01.16937933.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.SimpleFileServlet.writeResponseToClient 689
10/11/11 22:36:03:377 GMT 00000024 servlet I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: axis2_war [/axis2] [/axis2-web/listServices.jsp]: Initial
ization successful.
10/11/11 22:36:03:413 GMT 00000024 servlet I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: axis2_war [/axis2] [/axis2-web/include/link-footer.jsp]:
Initialization successful.
10/11/11 22:36:05:820 GMT 00000024 SystemOut O INFO getData request failed for dialect, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/
java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl, method=getDomConfig()Lorg/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration;, pc=0
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.newDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchemaElement(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:115)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchema(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:103)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.serialize_internal(XmlSchema.java:499)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.write(XmlSchema.java:473)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.generateOM(AxisService2WSDL11.java:211)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.outputInlineForm(WSDLDataLocator.java:131)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.getData(WSDLDataLocator.java:73)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:81)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getData(AxisService.java:2861)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1545)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1355)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:198)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:258)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
10/11/11 22:36:05:820 GMT 00000024 servlet E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods
of the servlet AxisServlet in application axis2_war. Exception created : org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.DataRetrievalException: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated;
class=org/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl, method=getDomConfig()Lorg/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration;, pc=0
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:85)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getData(AxisService.java:2861)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1545)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1355)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:198)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:258)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl, method=getDomConfig()Lorg/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguratio
n;, pc=0
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.newDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchemaElement(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:115)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchema(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:103)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.serialize_internal(XmlSchema.java:499)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.write(XmlSchema.java:473)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.generateOM(AxisService2WSDL11.java:211)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.outputInlineForm(WSDLDataLocator.java:131)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.getData(WSDLDataLocator.java:73)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:81)
... 27 more

10/11/11 22:36:05:828 GMT 00000024 FfdcProvider I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere7\AppServer\profiles\App
Srv01\logs\ffdc\server1_634d634d_11.11.10_22.36.05.82637934.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest() 298
10/11/11 22:36:05:832 GMT 00000024 webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: Servlet Error-AxisServlet: org.apache.axis2.dataretri
eval.DataRetrievalException: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl, method=getDomConfig()Lorg/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration;, p
c=0
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:85)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getData(AxisService.java:2861)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1545)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1355)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:198)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:258)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl, method=getDomConfig()Lorg/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguratio
n;, pc=0
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.newDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchemaElement(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:115)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchema(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:103)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.serialize_internal(XmlSchema.java:499)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.write(XmlSchema.java:473)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.generateOM(AxisService2WSDL11.java:211)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.outputInlineForm(WSDLDataLocator.java:131)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.getData(WSDLDataLocator.java:73)
at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:81)
... 27 more

10/11/11 22:36:05:900 GMT 00000024 servlet I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: axis2_war [/axis2] [/axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp]: Initi
alization successful.
10/11/11 22:36:05:912 GMT 00000024 servlet E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods
of the servlet /axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp in application axis2_war. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.getWriter(SRTServletResponse.java:646)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:187)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:175)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:262)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:177)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:144)
at com.ibm._jsp._error500._jspService(_error500.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:335)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:325)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3118)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3643)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

10/11/11 22:36:05:919 GMT 00000024 LocalTranCoor E WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
10/11/11 22:36:05:951 GMT 00000024 servlet E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods
of the servlet /axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp in application axis2_war. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.getWriter(SRTServletResponse.java:646)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:187)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:175)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:262)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:177)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:144)
at com.ibm._jsp._error500._jspService(_error500.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:644)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3643)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

10/11/11 22:36:05:958 GMT 00000024 LocalTranCoor E WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
10/11/11 22:36:06:043 GMT 00000024 FfdcProvider I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere7\AppServer\profiles\App
Srv01\logs\ffdc\server1_634d634d_11.11.10_22.36.05.96237935.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleError 912
10/11/11 22:36:06:049 GMT 00000024 webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception The server cannot use the error page spec
ified for your application because of the exception printed below.
10/11/11 22:36:06:054 GMT 00000024 webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
10/11/11 22:36:06:128 GMT 00000024 FfdcProvider I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere7\AppServer\profiles\App
Srv01\logs\ffdc\server1_634d634d_11.11.10_22.36.06.05937936.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.reportRecursiveError 985
```

Could you please help me sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I originally wrote the [configuration guide for WebSphere](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html#WebSphere) I tested that the WSDL generation works correctly, and it still does for me on WAS 7.0.0.15. On the other hand, there is a known issue with the XmlBeans library packaged with Axis2. That library contains a couple of DOM interfaces (in the org.w3c.dom package) that may cause issues with class loaders that don't use a simple parent-first policy. We originally [observed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4901) that with the Axis2 Eclipse plugins, but it may also be the root cause of the issue you encountered.

To check that the issue is caused by this, you should test again after removing the xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar from the Axis2 WAR.

Comment: Hmm...will try that and post the comments here...I just want to add one more thing that I am using apache-commons-pool for Object pooling along with Spring 2.5.6 ... can common-pools cause this as well??

Comment: The issue is related to interfaces defined in the org.w3c.dom package. AFAIK commons-pool has no relationship to DOM, so I would be very surprised if it has something to do with that issue.

Comment: Tried but no use...also I tried with axis1.5.3, 1.5.5, 1.5.6...downloading 1.6.1 (latest) to check if that works

Comment: I was able to reproduce the original issue with WAS 7.0.0.0 and it disappears when removing xmlbeans. However, I'm unable to reproduce the second issue. What is interesting is that in your case, the JRE tries to use IBM's XSLT processor although the Axis2 contains Xalan. Did you set any system property related to JAXP?

Answer (score 1):

Tried by removing the xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar from WEB-INF/lib directory and re-deployed the axis2.war but this time I am getting following exception when click on Web Service for its WSDL;

```
Initialization successful.
[15/11/11 14:12:47:813 GMT] 00000017 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods
 of the servlet AxisServlet in application axis2_war. Exception created : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0614] The processor h
as encountered an internal error condition.  Please report the problem and provide the following information: Method not found: class = interface org.apache.xml.serializer.Ser
ializationHandler method = startAttribute args = [class java.lang.String]
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1553)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1355)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:198)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:258)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0614] The processor has encountered an internal error con
dition.  Please report the problem and provide the following information: Method not found: class = interface org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler method = startAttr
ibute args = [class java.lang.String]
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettify(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:142)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1550)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0614] The processor has encountered an internal error condition.  Please report the problem and provide the foll
owing information: Method not found: class = interface org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler method = startAttribute args = [class java.lang.String]
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.ConfigurationErrorHandler.report(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.utils.Reporter.report(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl.createTemplates(Unknown Source)
        ... 30 more

[15/11/11 14:12:47:818 GMT] 00000017 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[AxisServlet]: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0614] The processor has encountered an internal error condition.  Please report the problem and provide the following inf
ormation: Method not found: class = interface org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler method = startAttribute args = [class java.lang.String]
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1553)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1355)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:198)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:258)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0614] The processor has encountered an internal error con
dition.  Please report the problem and provide the following information: Method not found: class = interface org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler method = startAttr
ibute args = [class java.lang.String]
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettify(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:142)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1550)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0614] The processor has encountered an internal error condition.  Please report the problem and provide the foll
owing information: Method not found: class = interface org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler method = startAttribute args = [class java.lang.String]
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.ConfigurationErrorHandler.report(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.utils.Reporter.report(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl.createTemplates(Unknown Source)
        ... 30 more

[15/11/11 14:12:47:994 GMT] 00000017 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [axis2_war] [/axis2] [/axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp]: Initi
alization successful.
[15/11/11 14:12:48:014 GMT] 00000017 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods
 of the servlet /axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp in application axis2_war. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.getWriter(SRTServletResponse.java:646)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:187)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:175)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:262)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:177)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:144)
        at com.ibm._jsp._error500._jspService(_error500.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:335)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:325)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3118)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3643)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

[15/11/11 14:12:48:021 GMT] 00000017 LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[15/11/11 14:12:48:028 GMT] 00000017 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods
 of the servlet /axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp in application axis2_war. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.getWriter(SRTServletResponse.java:646)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:187)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:175)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:262)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:177)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:144)
        at com.ibm._jsp._error500._jspService(_error500.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:644)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3124)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3643)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

[15/11/11 14:12:48:033 GMT] 00000017 LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[15/11/11 14:12:48:038 GMT] 00000017 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page spec
ified for your application because of the exception printed below.
[15/11/11 14:12:48:045 GMT] 00000017 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
```

Deployment, start and viewing the list of web services deployed has no problem. But as soon as I click on any service to view its WSDL, it crashing.

Also, why I asked for commons-pool.jar (which I already tested by removing has no effect anyway) is because start of this year I deployed the axis2.1.5.3.war on WAS7 without commons-pool and spring (at that time my application was not using spring or pooling) and it worked.

Regards,

--

SJunejo

Comment: Hey SJunejo, just wanted to let you know you can edit your original post with the edit button at the bottom to append your findings.

Comment: Thanks....The error I got after removing the xmlbean2-2.3.0.jar is because of my WAS instance got corrupted somehow. I re-installed WAS on my machine and it worked.